# Databinding Event listener

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-imagebutton

I am trying to set an event listener to an `ImageButton` but I keep getting this error.

```
Error:(48, 36) Could not resolve handler::onSelectPictureClicked as a listener.
```

Here is what my layout looks like.

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="handler"
        type="CompleteProfileActivityHandler"/>
</data>    
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_badge_upload"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/select_picture"
            android:id="@+id/complete_profile_picture_select"
            android:onClick="@{handler::onSelectPictureClicked}"/>
```

And here's my handler class

```
public class CompleteProfileActivityHandler{
    public void onSelectPictureClicked(View view){
        choosePicture();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. ;)

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured out what the problem was. 
I did not bind the handler to the view in the Activity.

Here's how I did it:

```
binding.setHandler(new CompleteProfileActivityHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your listenr class must implements View.OnClickListener class

```
 public class CompleteProfileActivityHandler implements View.OnClickListener{
public void onSelectPictureClicked(View view){
    choosePicture();
}
```

}

you have to wrate your code on the callback method of this interface.

Comment: instead of use your onSelectPictureClicked , implement des callback

Comment: The doc [https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html] doesn't say that.
Moreso, implementing `View.OnClickListener` means I have to override the `onClick(View view)` method. 
Which defeats the whole purpose of using databinding in the first place.